# How to make default focus on the search bar on a web page, as Google does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a website. It is nearly completed, just a few details to be done.

I have a small problem and wasn't able to find the solution on internet.

When the index page on the site is loaded I want the focus to be on the search bar automatically, so that a person can just load the page and start typing in order to search.

The site has the jquery library included.

Comment: HTML `autofocus` attribute

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish that by using the [`autofocus`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control%3a-the-autofocus-attribute) attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="searchbar" autofocus />
```

Comment: Hello,You are correct but its HTML5 ,what about IE8 Support?

Comment: @PratikJoshi, then you can check [this link](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-autofocus.php).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with below 3 methods, may these helps you :

1) `<input type="text" id="search" name="search" autofocus />`

2) `$(function(){
        $("#search").focus();
    });`

3) `window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("search").focus();
    };`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

`<input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" />`

or

try `tabindex="1"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery:

```
<script> $(function(){ $('#elementID').focus(); }); </script>
```

Or in pure HTML:

```
<input type="search" autofocus="autofocus">
```

but that requires browser supporting HTML5 autofocus attribute, so jQuery solution is more realiable.